# Post request to Node returns 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I have this in jQuery :

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        data : mydata,
        url : '/routerfunction',
        dataType : 'String',
        success : function(data)
        {
            //do stuff

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error)
        {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status);
        },


    }
```

And I have this in index.js(node)

```
router.post('/routerfunction/:mydata', function(req,res)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

And I have this in app.js(node)

```
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
```

When I do a POST request to routerfunction, I get 404 error. I have really tried to find the bug but I couldn't.. Where could the bug be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm non intimately familiar with node, but `'/routerfunction/:mydata'` makes it seem like you are expecting the data to be on the url.  Which is not how POST requests are.  The data is in the request body.

Comment: It miss in your ajax url something after routerfunction, your node is waiting smth like /routerfunction/data as url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This route:

```
router.post('/routerfunction/:mydata', ...
```

needs a URL like:

```
/routerfunction/SOMETHING
```

and will not match:

```
/routerfunction
```

so the 404 is correct here.

You would need:

```
router.post('/routerfunction', ...
```

to match that request.

Keep in mind that you also need a `body-parser` to parse the body which will include the data sent in the AJAX request which you will then be able to access with `req.body` - see those answers for some examples of that:

- [Running a node.js file from a click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241464/running-a-node-js-file-from-a-click-event/45243173#45243173)
- [Simple Node/Express app, the functional programming way (How to handle side-effects in JavaScript?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192989/simple-node-express-app-the-functional-programming-way-how-to-handle-side-effe/45194479#45194479)
- [Node.js send data to backend with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105992/node-js-send-data-to-backend-with-ajax/45106233#45106233)